# call a clojurescript function by string name

Tags: clojurescript

I'm searching for a way to call a function given its string name in clojureScript.

Something like:

```
(call "my-fun" args)
```

Any help welcome

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12020663/62082 may provide some help

Answer (score 5):

A pretty hackish solution that should work:

```
(ns eval.core
  (:require [clojure.string :as str]))

(defn ->js [var-name]
      (-> var-name
          (str/replace #"/" ".")
          (str/replace #"-" "_")))


(defn invoke [function-name & args]
      (let [fun (js/eval (->js function-name))]
           (apply fun args)))

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;; Usage:

(ns example.core
  (:require [eval.core :as e]))

(defn ^:export my-fn [arg1 arg2]     ;; Note the export!
      (println arg1 arg2)
      arg2)

(e/invoke "example.core/my-fn" 5 6)                       ;=> 5 6
```

Answer (score 4):

I needed a way of calling a function whose ns/name is loaded dynamically.  As noted, there is no supported way of doing so.  However, that's what hacks are for.  Here's what I ended up doing:

Calling cljs:

```
(js/proxy "my-ns/my-fun" args)
```

Proxy.js:

```
function proxy() {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  var nsFunc = args[0].replace(/-/g, "_").replace(/\//g, ".");
  eval(nsFunc).apply(null, args.slice(1));
}
```

Dynamically resolved cljs:

```
(ns my-ns)
(defn ^:export my-fun [args] ...)
```

The export metadata tells the closure compiler not to munge the name, so this works even with advanced mode compilation.  Needless to say, this isn't rock-solid code that's guaranteed to work in the future - but you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible, as once you use the advanced mode compilation of clojurescript then all function names are "munged", so there would be no way to map a string to a munged function when you wanted to call it

Answer (score 1):

As long as you don't use advanced optimization for the compiler:

```
(def global (this-as this this))

(defn call [fname & args]
  (.apply (aget global fname) global args))

(call "String" 123)
```

`global` is bound to the [global object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects) for any platform by using the `this` operator in the global scope. You may use `.call` instead of `.apply` as in:

```
(.call (aget global "String") global 123)
```

The same technique can also be used with other objects than the global.